# Laravel User Registration

Tags: php, authentication, registration, laravel-5

I'm looking for a way for users that are logged in to register new users. I don't want unregistered users creating new users. The problem that I'm coming up against is that Laravel does a lot of rerouting when you use their registration controllers so that it auto reroutes you away from the registration page if you are already logged in. Is there a way that I can get around this functionality without having to rewrite all of the registration logic?

I've tried simply adding auth middleware to the registration route but it immediately reroutes to the home page of the app before you hit the registration view. If I create a route that redirects to the registration view like this-

```
Route::get('register', function(){
  return view('auth.register');
});
```

It will give me the registration page but silently fail to add any users to the database. I think it may be because the RegistersUsers class has use RedirectsUsers as its first statement. Short of rewriting the code there is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I'm using Laravel 5.2 with the make:auth standard views

Comment: Why won't you just create a record in the users table just like any other record? why are you trying to use the register method that laravel provides?